# Could not broadcast input array from shape (320,320,1,8) into shape (320,320,1)

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, reshape, multiclass-classification, semantic-segmentation

Hi everyone Really need your help cause I am stuck with this problem for quite sometimes already

I want to perform multi- class segmentation. My images are in 0 to 255 values, while my masks are between 0 to 7 values. 0 represents the background while there are 7 objects.

For this reason, I encode my mask as one-hit encoded arrays using this codes:

```
def create_segmentation_generator_train(img_path, mask_path, BATCH_SIZE):
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1./255)
    img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    def one_hot_encode_mask(mask):
        # Assuming mask values are integers from 0 to 7
        num_classes = 8  # 7 object classes + 1 background
        one_hot_mask = tf.one_hot(mask, num_classes)
        return one_hot_mask

    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(dtype='float32', preprocessing_function=one_hot_encode_mask, **data_gen_args)

    img_generator = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(mask_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    
    return zip(img_generator, mask_generator)
```

Then, when i wanted to train my model, i got these errors: "could not broadcast input array from shape (320,320,1,8) into shape (320,320,1). "

I understand why this happened. The image and mask are not the same shape anymore.

But, what is the best approach of solving this in your opinions? Reshape the image to the mask shape? What would the 4th dimension of the images be?

These are my whole codes:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import cv2


# Define constants
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 320
IMAGE_WIDTH = 320
IMG_SIZE = (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN = 16
BATCH_SIZE_TEST = 16
SEED = 909

data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/data'
data_dir_train = os.path.join(data_dir, 'training')
data_dir_train_image = os.path.join(data_dir_train, 'img')
data_dir_train_mask = os.path.join(data_dir_train, 'mask')

data_dir_test = os.path.join(data_dir, 'test')
data_dir_test_image = os.path.join(data_dir_test, 'img')
data_dir_test_mask = os.path.join(data_dir_test, 'mask')

NUM_TRAIN = 3840
NUM_TEST = 960
NUM_OF_EPOCHS = 10


def create_segmentation_generator_train(img_path, mask_path, BATCH_SIZE):
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1./255)
    img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    def one_hot_encode_mask(mask):
        # Assuming mask values are integers from 0 to 7
        num_classes = 8  # 7 object classes + 1 background
        one_hot_mask = tf.one_hot(mask, num_classes)
        return one_hot_mask

    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(dtype='float32', preprocessing_function=one_hot_encode_mask, **data_gen_args)
    img_generator = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(mask_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    
    return zip(img_generator, mask_generator)


def create_segmentation_generator_test(img_path, mask_path, BATCH_SIZE):
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale=1./255)
    img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    def one_hot_encode_mask(mask):
        # Assuming mask values are integers from 0 to 7
        num_classes = 8  # 7 object classes + 1 background
        one_hot_mask = tf.one_hot(mask, num_classes)
        return one_hot_mask

    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(dtype='float32', preprocessing_function=one_hot_encode_mask, **data_gen_args)
    img_generator = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(img_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(mask_path, target_size=IMG_SIZE, class_mode=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=SEED)
    
    return zip(img_generator, mask_generator)


train_generator = create_segmentation_generator_train(data_dir_train_image, data_dir_train_mask, BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN)
test_generator = create_segmentation_generator_test(data_dir_test_image, data_dir_test_mask, BATCH_SIZE_TEST)


def display(display_list):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    title = ['Input Image', 'True Mask', 'Predicted Mask']
    for i in range(len(display_list)):
        plt.subplot(1, len(display_list), i + 1)
        plt.title(title[i])
        plt.imshow(tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(display_list[i]), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()


def show_dataset(datagen, num=1):
    for i in range(0, num):
        image, mask = next(datagen)
        mask = mask[0]  # Get the first mask
        mask = np.argmax(mask, axis=-1)  # Convert one-hot encoded mask to integer labels

        # Resize the image to match the mask dimensions
        image = cv2.resize(image[0], (mask.shape[1], mask.shape[0]))

        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.title('Input Image (Resized)')
        plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')

        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.title('Mask (Classes 0-8)')
        plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')

        plt.show()


show_dataset(train_generator, 1)


def unet(n_levels, initial_features=32, n_blocks=2, kernel_size=3, pooling_size=2, in_channels=1, num_classes=8): # Change out_channels to 8
    #n_blocks = how many conv in each level
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, in_channels))
    x = inputs

    convpars = dict(kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')

    #downstream
    skips = {}
    for level in range(n_levels):
        for _ in range (n_blocks):
            x = keras.layers.Conv2D(initial_features * 2 ** level, **convpars)(x)
        if level < n_levels - 1:
            skips[level] = x-1
            x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pooling_size)(x)

    #upstream
    for level in reversed(range(n_levels-1)):
        x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(initial_features * 2 ** level, strides=pooling_size, **convpars)(x)
        x = keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skips[level]])
        for _ in range (n_blocks):
            x = keras.layers.Conv2D(initial_features * 2 ** level, **convpars)(x)

    #output
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=1, activation='softmax',  padding='same')(x)

    return keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[x], name=f'UNET-L{n_levels}-F{initial_features}')

EPOCH_STEP_TRAIN = NUM_TRAIN // BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN
EPOCH_STEP_TEST = NUM_TEST // BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN

model = unet(4)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.summary()

history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, steps_per_epoch=EPOCH_STEP_TRAIN, validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=EPOCH_STEP_TEST, epochs=NUM_OF_EPOCHS)
```

Comment: So you mean the masks are your labels and you train the image (320, 320, 1) to have the labels (320, 320, 1, 8)?

Comment: Would you share the full error stack to know better what could have happened

Comment: My assumption would be that you don't need to hot-encode your mask (labels) just keep them with the shape (320, 320, 1) and then use as a loss the sparse category entropy.